# HttpSessionListener in Google Guice web application

Tags: java, servlets, dependency-injection, guice, servlet-listeners

I need to perform an action, which will access items in the [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html), when the Guice Servlet session expires. (*Why?* To go through open websocket connections for the session to be destroyed and close them; these connections are kept in the `ServletContext`.)

To achieve this in the basic Servlet web application, one would implement an [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) and hook into the `sessionDestroyed` method.

How would one achieve this for a web application that uses [Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Servlets) for dependency injection?

Recall the requirement to be able to access `ServletContext`; I already encountered [this forum conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-guice/9gsVec6HeKM), but didn't find it that helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'Guice way' to add session listeners. Sadly. But there's no problem in accessing the servlet context from session listeners.

Register session listener:

```
public class MyServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {
    private Injector    injector;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyAppModule());

        registerSessionListeners(servletContextEvent.getServletContext(), injector);

        super.contextInitialized(servletContextEvent);
    }

    private void registerSessionListeners(final ServletContext servletContext, final Injector injector) {
        servletContext.addListener(injector.getInstance(WebsocketCloser.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return injector;
    }

}
```

Access servlet context is session listener:

```
public class WebsocketCloser implements HttpSessionListener {
    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(final HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        // no-op
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(final HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        // do cleanup: httpSessionEvent.getSession().getServletContext();
    }
}
```